# True Vault blob store

Tags: blobstorage, truevault

i am working on true vault blob store. truevault is complete working fine but creating problem in uploading and downloading pdf or any other file. i download the source code from [Github](https://github.com/vavrecan/truevault-php) i cannot view any message or file name. if any idea about true vault or any one worked on this api kindly help me. thanx

```
// blobs

$response = $blobs->upload("input_file_1.bin");

$blobId = $response["blob_id"];

$blobs->upload("input_file_2.bin", $blobId); // replace existing

$blobs->download($blobId, "output_file.bin");
```

Answer (score 1):

first parameter in upload method is local file path, same for second parameter in download method. I will add better explanation to the documentation.

Comment: yes please add some different examples so other can work on it easily